# How to reset fields values out of html form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to reset `<INPUT>` and `<TEXTAREA>` values with jquery `click()` if these elements are **not** part of any `<FORM>`?

Comment: Would be great if you can share some code.

Comment: you can just use the id of the elements to reset it. I think for input it will be $(#id).val('') for textarea $(#id).html('')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear text area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284960/clear-text-area)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the values using `defaultValue` property, both `HTMLTextAreaElement` and `HTMLInputElement` support the property, the default value is the value as originally specified in HTML that created these objects.

```
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
   $('input, textarea').val(function() {
       return this.defaultValue;
   });
});
```

In case that you only want to reset the values of inputs and textareas that don't belong to a form element you  can use `.filter()` method:

```
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
   $('input, textarea').filter(function() {
       return !this.form;
   }).val(function() {
       return this.defaultValue;
   });
});
```

If the `form` property is `null` the input/textarea is not descendant of a form element.

http://jsfiddle.net/E2tbk/

Comment: @Sergio I was updating the answer. The second snippet covers this.

Comment: @undefined, ok, great!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var elements = $('input,textarea');
$('button').click(function () {
    elements.each(function () {
        if (!this.form) this.value = this.defaultValue;
    });
})
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfNq9/5/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution stores the initial values in the `data-oldvalue` attribute of the element. When you click the restore button it sets the values back to the initial ones.

Some pointed out you should use `.html()` to set the value of the `textarea`. I tried this but it did not set the value while `.val()` did

```
$("input").each(function() {   
    $(this).attr("data-oldvalue", $(this).val());
});

$("textarea").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-oldvalue", $(this).html());
});


$("button").click(function() {

    console.log($(this).attr("data-oldvalue"));

    $("input").each(function() {   
        $(this).val($(this).attr("data-oldvalue"));     
    });

    $("textarea").each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("data-oldvalue"));    
    });

});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/zvPK7/

Comment: No, not erase. I had some value before edit, than after click old value must be returned.

Comment: I dont think $("textarea").val(""); will work. But I may be wrong .. you need .html('') here.

Comment: The you first need to store all those values beforehand and then restore them I will create an example.

Comment: use some hidden variables.. store the values there and then again restore them.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
document.getElementById('yourInputID').value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('#click').on('click', function() {

    $("input[type='text'], textarea").val('');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This...

```
$('#btnID').click(function(){
        $('#FormID')[0].reset();
});
```