# How do I clear a textarea with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

This question has been answered, but for future reference here is a full example.

You can click the add button and clear button as many times as you want and it will work. But once you type something in the text box, then the clear and and add buttons do not work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").click(function(){

        $("#box").append("Test, ")
    });

    $("#clean").click(function(){
        $("#box").text("")
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="add">ADD</button><br/>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="box"></textarea><br/>
<button id="clean">Clear Box</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use $("#textarea").val('');

Comment: Please post a [mcve] demonstrating the issue

Comment: for those having problem with event handlers, here is a workaround answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284960/clear-text-area/54265441#54265441

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When dealing with elements that expect input from the user you should use jQuery's `val` function:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#b1').click(function() {
      $("#textarea").val($("#textarea").val() + "This is a test");
  });
  $('#c1').click(function() {
    $("#textarea").val("")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea><br />
<button id="b1">Append</button> <button id="c1">Clear</button>
```

The `append` function changes the `DOM`, and this is not what you are trying to do here (This is what breaks the default behavior of the `textarea` element).

Comment: Thank you so much. That issue was driving me crazy.