# After changing text in textarea is not changing when try to change using drop-down list text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have three multi-select dropdown lists and after selection from these dropdown list user press the submit button and the list text show in textarea but if user change some text in textarea and then again select another list from the dropdown then press submit the text is not changing in textarea.
I tried some solutions such as one the guy said use `$("#total_selections").val("");` instead of             `$("#total_selections").html("");` but after this nothing is showing in textarea.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="selection_button" disabled>Select Tags</button>
 </div>
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Formula, new { @class = "form-control", id = "total_selections" })

$("#selection_button").click(function () {
            $("#tag_creation").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#total_selections").val("");
            SelectedItemArray();
        });
    });


    function SelectedItemArray() {
        var datas = new Array();
        var datas = $('.add_item option:selected').map(function ()
        {
            return $(this).text() || undefined;
            }).get();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("selectedTags","CalculatedTags")",
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'selectedTags': datas }),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#total_selections").append(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you add more html code or a demo code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clear a textarea with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984133/how-do-i-clear-a-textarea-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#selection_button").click(function () {
               var  sel = $('#add_item option:selected').val();
     const ele= `<p style = "display:inline; background-color: #e9ebee; color: black; margin: 2px; padding: 1px;"> ${sel} <span style="cursor: pointer" onclick= "this.parentElement.remove()"> x</span> </p>`;
     $("#total_selections").append(ele);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="add_item">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

  <button type="button"  id="selection_button" >Select Tags</button>
<div contenteditable="false" style="min-height:50px; border:1px solid black; 
 width:300px;" id="total_selections"></div>
```

The append function changes the DOM, and this is not what you are trying to do here (This is what breaks the default behavior of the textarea element).

Comment: not working getting null in textarea when using .val() but getting text when using .text() or .html

Comment: Check selected value and data through console it should work

Comment: sorry i made a silly mistake i should use  $("#total_selections").val(data);   instead of this  $("#total_selections").append(data);

Comment: Hi I have another question can I make these selections in Textarea unchangeable i mean saab audi are uneditable but we can insert something between them something like saab+audi=car

Comment: i didnot get what u wanna say! do you want to make textarea readonly ?

Comment: yes each selected text from dropdown should be only read-only in textarea

Comment: I don't want to make the whole Textarea read-only instead I just want to make read-only the selected items from the dropdown list

Comment: you could not be able to do this in textarea! check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea/4705882