# How to clear a textarea value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate keycode entry by adding an alert when a user types a key that isn't expected, and then clearing the text area. The alert functions correctly but the text area isn't clearing.

I've checked the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/), but I can't see an area with my `.val()` line. I've also tried this: `$("#noteNumberInput").attr('value', "");`

Scenario: I type 1-9 in the text box and get no alert (works fine), if I type a letter a-z for example, the alert pops up but the letter remains in the text box.

## EDIT:

Something I've noticed is that it does clear the textarea after the first key. If I type the letter 'a' and then 'b', the 'a' is removed and replaced with a 'b'.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="noteNumberInput" placeholder="Note number"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var noteNumberInput = document.getElementById("noteNumberInput");

//VALIDATE NOTE NUMBER TEXTAREA
function validate(key) {
    var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
    //comparing pressed keycodes
    if (keycode === 8 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57) {
        alert("Please only enter the note number e.g. 1, 2..14 etc.");
        $("#noteNumberInput").val("");
        return false;
    }
}

noteNumberInput.addEventListener("keydown", validate);
```

Comment: Do you see the alert before the value isn't being cleared?

Comment: The alert shows when an incorrect key is pressed, and then after I close the alert the charcterappears in the textbox.

Comment: Are you doing this on keydown? Try doing it on keyup.

Comment: @webbm Yeah that's working now, thank you. Would you like to submit it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: for those having problem with event handlers, here is a workaround answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284960/clear-text-area/54265441#54265441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `noteNumberInput.addEventListener("keydown", validate);` to use `keyup`

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$("#noteNumberInput").val('');`, it removes all the content of the textarea, so if that's not what is happening, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah i figured that was the case but clearing the text box is the last line of the function except for return false so it shoudl clear the box and finish

Answer (score 1):

Using `$("#noteNumberInput").val()` will clear the textarea

**EDIT**

The problem is the `keydown` handler. In this case the function will be triggered followed by the display of alert & then the text area will be populated. But on using `keyup` the function will be triggered on release of the key.So by that time the `textarea` will be populated with value.

Change the `keydown` to `keyup`

```
var noteNumberInput = document.getElementById("noteNumberInput");
noteNumberInput.addEventListener("keyup", validate);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/j91hf4xj/)

Comment: Unfortunatley doesn't work, the character still displays after the alert message is removed.

Comment: @EthanBristow how are you calling validate function?

Answer (score 0):

Your only asking for the `validate()` function to actually execute when you've pressed the *next key*.

Answer (score 0):

I think that´s not the best idea to trigger key events, because cut and paste and drag and drop can also change the input element.

try this:

```
Element.addEventListener('input', function(){
    this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '');
});
```

this must be adapted to textarea...