# How to clear textarea value with jquery?

Tags: jquery

```html
<textarea class="cleditor" name="category_description" id="category_description" rows="3"></textarea>
```

```js
$("#category_description").val('');
```

textarea value  not clear!!

Comment: Please, add your requirement how you exactly want to clear textarea.

Comment: Code shown will work fine assuming the textarea exists when you run it. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: for those having problem with event handlers, here is a workaround answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284960/clear-text-area/54265441#54265441

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#category_description').val('');
```

It seems to work fine. Are you sure jquery is loaded and you really see the textarea on your screen and not your cleditor?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utwbqfhj/)

If you have the cleditor on your screen, you should probably use:

```
$('#category_description').cleditor().clear()
```

This is also described in the [getting started](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/gettingstarted#cleditorMethod) when you look in `.cleditor(options) Method > cleditor Object > Methods`

Comment: Jquery is loaded and another input type with jquery are work,

Comment: And you do see the textarea on your screen? Or do you see the cleditor? Could you please write a JSFiddle to demonstrate your problem?