# jQuery - clear textarea text content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can i clear textarea content using "onclick"?

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">System Main Message</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <textarea id="editor-area" name="sysMsg" class="form-control"><?PHP echo $mainIndex['sysMsg'] ?></textarea>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById['editor-area'].value = ''">Clear message</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use placeholder attribute or use  <a href="#" onclick="$('#editor-area').value('')">

Comment: for those having problem with event handlers, here is a workaround answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284960/clear-text-area/54265441#54265441

Answer (score 1):

use this. it will remove all the content of the text area

```js
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $('#editor-area').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor-area">
  test test test
</textarea>
<button id="target">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect brackets. Change `document.getElementById['editor-area']` to `document.getElementById('editor-area')` and then it works:

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">System Main Message</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <textarea id="editor-area" name="sysMsg" class="form-control">Textarea value</textarea>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('editor-area').value =''">Clear message</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `empty()` methods in Jquery.

```js
 $( "#clear" ).click(function() {
     $('#editor-area').empty();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">System Main Message</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <textarea id="editor-area" name="sysMsg" class="form-control">testing text</textarea>
        <a id="clear" href="#">Clear message</a>
    </div>
</div>
```